# Repeat main figure caption for subfigures, across page boundaries

Tags: subfloats

I have a figure consisting of two subfigures. For this, I use the subcaption package. Because of the page lay-out, these figures have to cross page boundaries. For this I use `\ContinuedFloat`. However, the main figure caption is only shown at the very bottom after the last subfigure.

I would like to have the main figure caption after both subfigures, and possibly show "(continued)" for each main figure caption after the first.

Any solution using subfigure is appreciated, or an alternative using e.g. multiple figures and manipulating figure numbering and referencing.

See the image below that I threw together in paint, for what I would like to achieve in Latex. [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that show how you currently add your subfigures?

Comment: Regarding "I use the subfigure package": The `subfigure` package is deprecated. Use the `subfig` of `subcaption` packages instead.

Comment: I was mistaken, I thought I used subfigure but that was a previous attempt. I actually am using subcaption now. Your answer did what I wanted, I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with the `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-A}
\caption{caption of first subfigure}\label{first}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{common caption}\label{whole}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-B}
\caption{caption of second subfigure}\label{second}
\end{subfigure}
\caption[]{common caption (continued)}
\end{figure}

See \ref{first}

See \ref{second}

See \ref{whole}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I thought I had tried it but it gave an error, but retrying now did make it work; I probably made a mistake before. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From my little experience with `\ContinuedFloat`, the command "freezes" the float counter only.
You can put whatever caption you want inside the `figure` environments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{% <- you can used you preferred tool to make subifgures here
        first subfigure
        \label{first-subfigure}
    }{%
        \rule{.9\textwidth}{.8\textheight}
    }
    \caption{First caption -- continued}
    \label{fig:splitted-figure-first}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
    \ContinuedFloat
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{% <- you can used you preferred tool to make subifgures here
        second subfigure
        \label{second-subfigure}
    }{%
        \rule{.9\textwidth}{.8\textheight}
    }
    \caption{Second caption}
    \label{fig:splitted-figure-second}
\end{figure}

\noindent{}Label of first part of figure: \ref{fig:splitted-figure-first}\\
Label of second part of figure: \ref{fig:splitted-figure-second}\\
Page of first part of figure: \pageref{fig:splitted-figure-first}\\
Page of second part of figure: \pageref{fig:splitted-figure-second}\\

\end{document}
```